# angular 4 json pipe - spaces not trimmed in pre tag

Tags: html, angular, pre

I have this json that I'm trying to pretty-print:

```
{
 "error": "BAD_RESULT",
 "status": 500,
 "description": "Something bad happenned."
}
```

This object is stored in a variable `errorMsg`, and displayed in html using the `pre` tag like so:

```
<pre>
   {{ errorMsg | json }}
</pre>
```

Unfortunately, when I inspect the element in the developers console, I see that the content inside the `pre` tag is padded with lots of spaces (right after the opening pre, and right before the closing pre), and that causes an indentation of the opening bracket. If I manually delete the spaces from the console, the json is displayed perfectly. How can it be solved? Is there a pure css solution or maybe with js?

Thanks.

EDIT:

My code was originally:

```
<pre>
   {{ errorMsg | json }}
</pre>
```

When it was supposed to be:

```
<pre>{{ errorMsg | json }}</pre>
```

Now it works.

Comment: What happens if you just take off the <pre> tags?

Comment: @DeborahK If I remove the pre tags then json appears in a single line

Comment: @Mister_L That was what I was going to suggest as the solution (because you *do* have a bunch of spaces inside the `<pre>`!), but you should edit it out of your question, post it as an answer, and accept that answer. It's perfectly fine to accept your own answer, and it will prevent the question staying "open".

Comment: this is soooo weird, thanks for positing the solution..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without having to rely on the indentation of your file, which might get messed with by formatting tools, I would suggest using something like the following.

```
<pre [innerText]="errorMsg | json"></pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to trim strings, you could use Javascript .trim() method.

```
var str = "       Hello World!        ";
alert(str.trim());
```

Output:
Hello world!

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

Comment: If I try JSON.stringify(err, null, 4).trim() it doesn't solve the problem